# Sublime text 3 layout single column key shortcut not working

Tags: 17.04, sublime-text

I am using Sublime text 3 (build 3131) and I have set the layout of the editor in 2 columns.However I want to go back to single by using <kbd>alt+shift+1</kbd>.However this doesn't work.I am using ubuntu 17.04.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Linux Mint so I changed to <kbd>alt+1</kbd> and it's work.

To change this, go in *Preferences > Keys bidings* and add this:

```
{
    "keys": ["alt+1"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1]]
    }
},
{
    "keys": ["alt+2"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard layout change option key bind. If it use "shift" and "alt" keys, bind to something else.
Also you can run at Sublime Console
 
`sublime.log_input(True)
sublime.log_commands(True)`
to know if Sublime Text log this keys

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I found a working solution (at leat for me) and I hope it will hep other people.

I had to adapt the key binding to the following:

```
{
    "keys": ["alt+shift+&"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1]]
    }
},
{
    "keys": ["alt+shift+é"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
},
```

I use a french keyboard layout actually and the symbols '1' and '&' as well as '2' and 'é' are respectively on the same key ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SO after 3 years I remembered to answer my own question. The problem had to do with Ubuntu Budgie. It had bind the combination I was using for the sublime text to do something else